# How to perform ASCII subtraction in java

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a `char[]` array named `temp` which only contains `a`,`b` or `c`. Now if the two adjacent characters in the array are distinct, ie `temp[j]` and `temp[j+1]` contains `a` and `b` respectively, I need to store `c` in `temp[j+1]` .

And for that, I defined,

```
private static final int CHARSUM = 294;
```

which is the sum of ASCII value of `a`,`b` and `c`. and what I tried was to subtract the sum of `temp[j]` and `temp[j+1]` from `294`.

```
temp[j+1] = CHARSUM-(temp[j]+temp[j+1]);
```

which should store the value `c` if the other values were `a` and `b`.
But here, **the problem is:**

> incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char

And I tried changing to:

- `private static final char CHARSUM = "294";`
- `temp[j+1] = (char)CHARSUM-(temp[j]+temp[j+1]);`
- `temp[j+1] = Character.getNumericValue(CHARSUM-(temp[j]+temp[j+1]));`

However, none of those did work and I did not find any other answers that would help me to solve the problem. So Any help to fix this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast the result of the subtraction to a char:

```
temp[j+1] = (char)(CHARSUM-(temp[j]+temp[j+1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a `char` is "really" a whole number between `0` and `65535`. If you want to assign an `int` outside that range to a `char` variable, an explicit cast is required.

For example

```
char c = 65535;        // ok
char c = 65536;        // doesn't compile
char c = (char) 65536; // compiles, but it's a lossy conversion
```

Even though for your values, `CHARSUM-(temp[j]+temp[j+1])` *is* always in that range, the compiler can't tell that because it is not a compile time constant. Therefore you need to apply a cast to the entire expression:

```
temp[j+1] = (char) (CHARSUM-(temp[j]+temp[j+1]));
```

Your approaches did not work, for reasons I'll explain:

- `"294"` is a `String`, not an `int`.
- The cast is only applied to `CHARSUM` - the entire expression is still an `int`.
- `getNumericValue` returns an `int` not a `char`, so you'd have to cast.

Comment: Thanks for helping to know more :-)